# How to save the changes made with a script

Tags: php

With this script, change the order of the lines in a text file, but I'd like to save the file as a new file. How can I do that?

```
<?php
$file = "menu2.txt";
$righe = file($file);
$numrighe = count($righe);

$portieri = array();
$difensori = array();
$aladestra = array();
$alasinistra = array();
$attaccante = array();


for($i=0; $i < $numrighe;$i++) {
    $riga = $righe[$i];
    list($giocatore, $ruolo) = preg_split("[>]", $riga);
    if(strcmp($ruolo,"Portiere")) { array_push($portieri, $giocatore); }
    else if(strcmp($ruolo,"Difensore")) { array_push($difensori, $giocatore); }
    else if(strcmp($ruolo,"Ala destra")) { array_push($aladestra, $giocatore); }
    else if(strcmp($ruolo,"Ala sinistra")) { array_push($alasinistra, $giocatore); }
    else if(strcmp($ruolo,"Attaccante")) { array_push($attaccante, $giocatore); }
}

?>
```

Comment: using [fwrite](http://php.net/fwrite)

Comment: You give very little information about your data. Which variable will hold the data you want to save?

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me but probably because of google translator or because they are prevented, but you probably will not understand it, I did it:

```
<?php
    $file = "menu2.txt";
    $righe = file($file);
    $numrighe = count($righe);

    $portieri = array();
    $difensori = array();
    $aladestra = array();
    $alasinistra = array();
    $attaccante = array();


    for($i=0; $i < $numrighe;$i++) {
        $riga = $righe[$i];
        list($giocatore, $ruolo) = preg_split("[>]", $riga);
        if(strcmp($ruolo,"Portiere")) { array_push($portieri, $giocatore); }
        else if(strcmp($ruolo,"Difensore")) { array_push($difensori, $giocatore); }
        else if(strcmp($ruolo,"Ala destra")) { array_push($aladestra, $giocatore); }
        else if(strcmp($ruolo,"Ala sinistra")) { array_push($alasinistra, $giocatore); }
        else if(strcmp($ruolo,"Attaccante")) { array_push($attaccante, $giocatore); }
    }


    // open your new file
    $newFile = fopen('newmenu2.txt', 'w');

    // write to your file using $newFile file handler,
    // with the imploded data you want to write into your file
    fwrite($newFile, implode("\n", $data));

    // close your file handler
    fclose($newFile);
    ?>
```

Notice: Undefined variable: data on line 29

Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed on line 29